# Bean Manipulation Fortify Static Scan vulnerability

Tags: security, javabeans, fortify

Is there a recommended library to use to fix "Bean Manipulation" vulnerability related with org.apache.commons.beanutils.populate (bean, paramMap)? I tried to write some custom method to validate the paramMap, but that did not resolve the issue.

regards
Sanjay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below refactoring seems to have removed the vulnerability from fortify scan:

```
    for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
      BeanUtils.setProperty(object, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```